# How to direct people to another page once submitting a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, function, email

I'm currently working on this page: http://www.maschineuk.com/landing-page

When people have entered their name and email address I want them to be re-directed to a page where they can download the song for free...

currently it just comes up with an alert box.

```
<script>
$('form').simpleContactForm(
{
senderEmail : "", // if you leave this field empty, the mailing address will be the email field of the form
url : "php/simpleContactForm.php", // path to the plugin php file
type: "POST",  
subject : "FREE DOWNLOAD - MASCHINE",    
clearAfterSend : true,              
errorClass : "error",                               
success : function() {
    alert('Sent Successfully!');
}   
});
```

How do I change the success function so that it directs them to another page? Or is there another way to do this?

After finding out that the following code will redirect after the form is submitted:

```
window.location="http://www.exampleurl.com";
```

Ho can I make it so that this page can be visited ONLY WHEN they have entered their email?

I dont want people being able to download the song without entering their email first...

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `window.location.href = url`?

Comment: I actually hate websites that redirect on submit. That makes it extremely hard to go back and edit/repost.

Comment: Well, can you suggest any other way in which to do this?

Answer (score 1):

add a `window.location.href`

```
success : function() {
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for that!  After a bit more googling i managed to find that out too...... works a treat..